# Issues with accessing information declared in different modules in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've got a python file(root.py) and another python file(button.py). When I define a button with an attribute (such as size_hint:0.1,1) in button.py using the kv language, root.py doesnt seem to be able to access that information.

When I define the same information using python in button.py, root.py seems to be able to access it.

ROOT.PY

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from buttons import *

Builder.load_string("""
<Root>:
    ButtonBar:
""")

class BtnBar(ButtonBar):
    print(self.size_hint) # prints [1,1] instead of [0.1,1]

class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class AppDev(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()
```

BUTTON.PY

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<ButtonBar>:
    size_hint: 0.1,1
""")

class ButtonBar(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

Root.py should be able to access any information I declare in button.py's Builder.load_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the object is instantiated, the right data will be accessable. You can use clock to make sure you get it after instantiation.
Also in your kv string, you probably want `BtnBar` instead of `ButtonBar`
Here is your root.py rewritten to do this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from buttons import *

Builder.load_string("""
<Root>:
    BtnBar: # corrected to BtnBar
""")

class BtnBar(ButtonBar):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BtnBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.get_data)

    def get_data(self, dt):
        print(self.size_hint) # prints on second frame

class Root(FloatLayout):
    pass

class AppDev(App):
    def build(self):
        return Root()

AppDev().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One other question if you can answer it, how do I access information from root.py in button.py. For example, I want to access Root.size from root.py. I tried 'from root import *' but that returns error. I also tried accessing 'self.parent.size' from ButtonBar but that returns None

Comment: Actually, I applied what you said in your answer and self.parent worked! I scheduled the clock for the next frame after the instantiation.

Comment: @moo5e great. :)